# Mule 3.7. Add custom SOAP header to web-service-consumer

Tags: web-services, soap, header, mule

I am trying to customize the soap header in Mule 3.7.  By default using the web-service-consumer I get the following:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" soap:mustUnderstand="1">
        <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-6CF0E33EE8AA1E3DB414700278333141">
            <wsse:Username>TEST/wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText"/>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
```

However, I would like to change the SOAP header to be:

```
<soap:Header>
<Security xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
    <UsernameToken>
        <Username>TEST</Username>
    </UsernameToken>
</Security>
```

Where in Mule do I need to add the below?

```
<set-property propertyName="soap.Authorization"
value="<auth>Bearer MWYxMDk4ZDktNzkyOC00Z</auth>"/>
```

Does the above need to be added in the ws:consumer-config below?

```
<ws:consumer-config name="WSConsumerConfig" wsdlLocation="${wsdl.location}"
service="aService" port="aServiceHttpPort" serviceAddress="${service.url}"
connectorConfig="HTTPRequestConfig" doc:name="Web Service Consumer">
```

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed by adding a message-property-transformer just before the call to the ws-consumer:

```
<message-properties-transformer doc:name="Message Properties">
                <add-message-property key="soap.header" value="${web.service.username.token}"/>
            </message-properties-transformer>
```

Comment: what is the key and value should be passed here?

Comment: @bekur, key doesn't matter here, whatever xml string you passed in value, same content gets added under header element.